2013 Opel Corsa has the following code “Crankshaft Position ,Camshaft position Correlation Bank 1 sensor A”
P0016 CODE:‘My 2013 Opel Corsa has the following code “Crankshaft Position ,Camshaft position Correlation Bank 1 sensor A”
I got the timing chain done a couple of weeks ago and the code was present prior to getting it done and remained after. When I cleared the code it usually popped back on after a couple of minutes. My mechanic said it was the crankshaft position sensor so I replaced that yesterday , cleared the codes and all seemed to be well , it didn’t reappear. But this morning when I restarted the car check engine light was back with the same code. Once the code is cleared I can drive it, turn it off and on repeatedly and it still stays off but as soon as drive an distance of around 30km(not necessarily in one drive) and turn the car on and off it comes back. I was thinking of replacing the camshaft sensor but the fact that it takes so long for the light to reappear since replacing the crankshaft position sensor compared to before it makes me think this probably isn’t the problem. The car is also performing perfectly with no driving issues. I’m no expert with cars so any advice would be greatly appreciated.’

When you did the timing chain did you replace it with brand new chain ? That error code is usually cranskhaft and camshaft are somewhat out of sync instead should be totally sync.
To check the chain you would have to remove camcovers or even timing cover, so to keep things simple can you check for any connectors in and around cranshaft that are not connected or bad wire condition, camshaft position sensors wire,connector condition.
Condition of anything around fuel injector area. Maybe check sparkplugs, coilpacks, generally condition of wire and connectors as much as you can.
